# If I install the Ubuntu Desktop on Ubuntu Server, will I still have the server kernel?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, gui

I know, I know, insert standard lecture of "You shouldn't install a GUI on a server OS!"
But, after reading this guide:

```
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/install-gui-in-ubuntu-server.html
```

It implies that if I install the GUI with:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Instead of:

```
sudo aptitude install --without-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

Then I will change my kernel from the Server kernel to the Desktop kernel.
Is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since 12.04, there is no difference in kernel between Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server since linux-image-server is merged into linux-image-generic.

Found on Ubuntu's [Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerFaq#Which_kernel_versions_or_types_are_available_on_the_Ubuntu_Server_CD.3F) page.

Comment: @ChrisPowell You are most welcome :)